# Delete information input by user

Tags: java

I am trying to make a movie database for some homework. Getting stuck adding deleting functionality. I get stuck trying when trying to re-add another movie because of my moivecount variable. If I delete movie3 if I have 4 movies then moviecount == 3 and when I try to add another movie it asks for movie4 again when I need to add movie3.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Interface {
private void run() 
{


    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Movie m1;
    Movie m2;
    Movie m3;
    Movie m4;

    String name, director;
    int size, duration, option;
    int moviecount = 0;

    m1 = new Movie();
    m2 = new Movie();
    m3 = new Movie();
    m4 = new Movie();

do {
    System.out.println("Import new movie:(0), Delete movie from Database (2), View Movies: (3),  Exit (9): ");
    option = console.nextInt();
    switch(option)
    {
        case 0: 
        if(moviecount == 0)
        {
                System.out.print("First Movie: ");
                name = console.next();
                m1.setName (name);
                System.out.print("Director: ");
                director = console.next();
                m1.setDirector (director);
                System.out.print("Size in MB: ");
                size = console.nextInt();
                m1.setSize(size);
                System.out.print("Duration in minutes: ");
                duration = console.nextInt();
                m1.setDuration(duration);
                moviecount++;
                break;


        }

        else if(moviecount == 1)
        {
                System.out.print("Second Movie: ");
                name = console.next();
                m2.setName (name);
                System.out.print("Director: ");
                director = console.next();
                m2.setDirector (director);
                System.out.print("Size in MB: ");
                size = console.nextInt();
                m2.setSize(size);
                System.out.print("Duration in minutes: ");
                duration = console.nextInt();
                m2.setDuration(duration);
                moviecount++;
                break;
        }

        else  if(moviecount == 2)
        {
                System.out.print("Third Movie: ");
                name = console.next();
                m3.setName (name);
                System.out.print("Director: ");
                director = console.next();
                m3.setDirector (director);
                System.out.print("Size in MB: ");
                size = console.nextInt();
                m3.setSize(size);
                System.out.print("Duration in minutes: ");
                duration = console.nextInt();
                m3.setDuration(duration);
                moviecount++;
                break;
        }

        else  if(moviecount == 3)
        {
                System.out.print("Fourth Movie: ");
                name = console.next();
                m4.setName (name);
                System.out.print("Director: ");
                director = console.next();
                m4.setDirector (director);
                System.out.print("Size in MB: ");
                size = console.nextInt();
                m4.setSize(size);
                System.out.print("Duration in minutes: ");
                duration = console.nextInt();
                m4.setDuration(duration);
                moviecount++;
                break;
        }

        else
        {
                System.out.print("Too many movies currently stored \n" );
                break;
        }

        case 2: System.out.print("Which movie to delete? (1), (2), (3), (4) \n");
        option = console.nextInt();
        switch(option)
        {
           case 1:  m1.setName(null);
                    m1.setDirector(null);
                    m1.setSize(0);
                    m1.setDuration(0);
                    System.out.print("Movie 1 deleted! ");
                    moviecount--;
                    break;           

           case 2:  m2.setName(null);
                    m2.setDirector(null);
                    m2.setSize(0);
                    m2.setDuration(0);
                    moviecount--;
                    break;

           case 3:  m3.setName(null);
                    m3.setDirector(null);
                    m3.setSize(0);
                    m3.setDuration(0);
                    moviecount--;
                    break;

           case 4:  m4.setName(null);
                    m4.setDirector(null);
                    m4.setSize(0);
                    m4.setDuration(0);
                    moviecount--;
                    break;

        }

        case 3: System.out.print("Movies stored in database: \n");
                System.out.print(m1.getName()+"\n"); 
                System.out.print(m2.getName()+"\n");
                System.out.print(m3.getName()+"\n");
                System.out.print(m4.getName()+"\n");










    } 
}
    while(option!=9);



}
public static void main(String[] args){
Interface intFace = new Interface();
intFace.run();
}
}
```

Comment: Better use List.

Comment: You are missing something very important here.  You should be using an array, `List`, `Map` or some other data structure to hold your `Movie` objects ... not variables called `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4` and so on.  Then to delete a Movie, you **remove** it from the data structure.  Basically, you need to throw away most of the copy-and-paste code that you have "written".

Comment: And if lists are too advanced, go for an array. The others are correct, using m1, m2,... variables, that is just wrong. What if you want to allow 5 movies? Or 50?

Comment: @GhostCat the task only needs it to allow up to 4.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your design. You are running into this problem because you are not actually storing your movies anywhere. You are just creating 4 different movie objects and printing them out. If you changed the order of your print statements, they would be in a different order.

You are going to need to add in some sort of data structure - any array, a list, or some other sort of collection to store your movies in.

For example you might create a `List` to store your movie data.

```
    //create new List called movieList
    List movieList = new ArrayList();

    //add movies to the list
    movieList.add(m1);
    movieList.add(m2);
    movieList.add(m3);
    movieList.add(m4);


    //remove movies from the list by position
    movieList.remove(0);
    movieList.remove(1);
    movieList.remove(2);
    movieList.remove(3);
```

You can add your movies to the list using the Lists's `add()` method, and remove them using the `remove()` method. Keep in mind that `remove` removes the element at the index you provide, and the index starts at 0.

So, for example to remove the first movie, you would call movieList.remove(0).
The second movie would be at index 1, etc.

Comment: We cannot use arrays as we have not learned about them yet, I believe we can use lists though. Is there a good tutorial for beginners? I have had a quick search and not found much. Also we must store our Movies in a MovieDatabase class, would the list be in there or in the Interface class?

Comment: your list would go in your MovieDatabase class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html is the official java documentation for list

Comment: Okay I really appreciate the help but this is a completely new concept to me so sorry if my questions sound stupid but I honestly have no clue what to do. How will this interact with the Interface class, do I still need the m1.setName etc? Will the list store all the information for the movie or juts the name?

Comment: The List will contain the movie objects - so yes, all the information.

The movies contain the movie data (name, director, size) and the list contains the movies.

Comment: Just for the record: in any reasonable curriculum you would learn about arrays before turning to List and ArrayList. So if your teacher doesn't want arrays, he will not like lists. Probably you should rather ask him for clarification.

Comment: @GhostCat Well they did say that we will not need any containers and to store each movie as its own variable, but I can't figure it out. I've been told that the task is poorly designed by numerous people.

Comment: See my answer then. Should tell you what you need to resolve that poorly designed assignment :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific implementation: you can't use that moviecount variable to determine in which slot you want to add a new move!

Instead: just walk over your movie objects. And push data into the first one that is empty.

Meaning: you could define a "isEmpty()" method on the Movie class that returns true if the name is null.

But just for the record: having and using these setter methods is a bad approach. Normally you would want to set all these values using the constructor of the movie class, as you don't want to allow to change that information later on.

And then you would simply do

```
movie1 = new...
```

when creating a new movie and

```
movie1 = null
```

to delete it later on. And then you can also easily check if a slot is taken:

```
if (movie1 == null) {...
```

Comment: Sorry I dont quite understand. Define a "isEmpty()" method in my Movie class? Also movie1 = new? Where has movie1 come from and new what? Do you mean m1 = new Movie()?

Comment: Yes. Well: more like new Movie(name,...) - providing the values that you are currently setting via those setter methods.